# Vertical direction of PVC tee used for vent only

Tags: plumbing, vent, pvc

If a PVC tee is used to drain, where the flow of fluid is descending, it is obvious it should be positioned (*T pedestal slightly pointing*) upwards.

But if the piping segment is used only to vent, with air streaming upwards, should the tee be installed upside down so that the pedestal directions matches the ascending flow of air?

Comment: What is "*pedestal or pedestal directions*"  What kind of PVC tee? What else interacts with the tee?  What are you trying to do? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Pedestal is the one of the three prongs of a tee that doesn't have another one directly opposite to it

Comment: Prongs? you mean openings? Meaning the opening that is at 90 degrees to the other two. OK. That is usually the inlet  receiving the waste from the fixture and the lower one is the outlet  to drain and the upper one is for the vent.   **What else interacts with the tee? What are you trying to do? What is the problem you are trying to solve?**

Comment: Yes, opening but in a normal tee, it is not 90°, more like 85

Comment: Unless you provide more details about what your problem is or why you want to install a tee (incorrectly?) on its side then we can not try to help you. Upside down? Vent tee, not sanitary tee? Describe, in detail, the venting you are trying to do please.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a sanitary tee to go from a horizontal vent pipe into a vertical vent the correct orientation is "upside down" from its normal usage.  The curve of the tee should go from the horizontal direction curving up toward the roof.  Air flows into the vent from outside to replace air pushed downstream by the falling waste, so the vent is oriented to allow smooth airflow from the roof side into the horizontal vent. [image: sanitary tee in upside down orientation]

Comment: This exactly answers my question, which apparently is not as obscurely formulated as suggested in the comments above

Comment: Does it make a difference if the vertical stack is a wet vent? I'm still using the horizontal pipe strictly for venting.

Comment: For reference, you can find this answer in the 2015 International Plumbing Code (3rd Printing as adopted by New York State) in Figure 706.3(10) PROPER USE OF DWV-PVC/ABS 90-DEGREE FITTINGS.  https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/IPC2015_NY/chapter-7-sanitary-drainage/IPC2015-Ch07-Sec706.3